# Download NuGet-package in VSTS task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm building a custom Release-task for VSTS. I'm building it with Node and Typescript. Is there any way that I, in my task, can download a NuGet-package? Something like this:

```
import nuget = require('nuget-lib');
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

async function run() {
    try {
        console.log('Starting... Will try to download latest nuget.')

        const package = nuget.fetch('Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools');
        // Do stuff with package...

        console.log('Task done!');
    }
    catch (err) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}

run();
```

My task needs some stuff in the NuGet-package, and I don't wish to include it in the package itself because then I need to update the package if the NuGet-package is updated.

I know that I can let my Build-step include the necessary packages in an artifact, but I want my Release-step to be able to run without those dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Just call [nuget.exe install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install) command in your code, which is similar to the NuGet task: [VSTS-tasks/Tasks/NuGet](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/NuGet)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Other stuff got in the way before I was able to test it.